# Batch rename of video files after finding its resolution height

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, batch-rename

Trying my first script, not going smoothly. Maybe someone knows of a program or can help point in the right direction. I want to sequentially find a large archive of video files resolutions - height only (I know 2 ways to accomplish this, using ffprobe and mediainfo); if 720 or 1080 append as a suffix, previous to the extension. If the file is not 720 or 1080 separate into 2 directories (650+ & 649-). I know how to find the resolution, create directories, move and rename files. I am having trouble specifically with the multiple files in sequential order, if/and/or use and how to pipe for the renaming with either ffprobe or mediainfo. Thanks.

Comment: Quick note: In Windows its called batch in linux its called bash

Just wanted to let you know :)

Comment: Read `man find xargs`. Wrap your height test and decision making in a `bash` script (Read `man bash`).

Comment: Thanks guys. Much appreciated. I'll read those man pages and see what I come up with over the next day or two. :)

Answer (score 3):

This simplistic example should get you started:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ ! -d "650+" ] && [ ! -d "649-" ]; then
  mkdir "650+" "649-"
fi

for f in *.mp4
do
height=$(ffprobe -v error -show_entries stream=height -of csv=p=0 "$f")
if [ "$height" -eq 1080 ] || [ "$height" -eq 720 ]; then
  mv "$f" "${f%.*}_$height.${f##*.}"
fi
if [ "$height" -lt 650 ]; then
  mv "$f" "649-"
else
  mv "$f" "650+"
fi

done
```

As you can see the logic isn't perfect because it only moves videos with a height less than 720 px into the appropriate directories, but it shows the basics. (Ran out of time to make it better due to a pending meeting.) Also, it's not recursive. Wasn't sure if that was a requirement.

Also see:

- [Getting width x height with `ffprobe`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29585066/)
- [Bash parameter expansion](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073) - helpful for renaming
- [Bash comparison operators](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html)
- [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) - to check for script errors and to provide suggestions

Comment: WOW!! thank you, I still haven't gotten back to it, hopefully this weekend. But man, I am very grateful! I can comprehend much of what I'm reading, just going to have to verify and I'll test it out, then get back to you. :D